# Issue faced while using Spark saveAsTable command

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have configured hive and i am using spark to write data frame into hive. i have configured hive ware house path in both spark configuration and hive configuration. My ware house location is hdfs://ip-address:8020/user/hive/warehouse in both the configuration. But when i use saveAsTable function in spark table serdeproperties path is coming as hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse. So while reading i am getting exception as unknown host namenode

Comment: Check your host file..

Comment: Is your association of DNS server and hostname correct? Do check your resolve.conf file.